Is it possible for two words to have the same underlying representation but different surface forms?
I'm trying to wrap my head around a mental concept and I was wondering if this was even possible, and how you would seperate the two using the exact same rules?

Please explain a little more what you mean. What is underlying representation for you?

Yes it is possible (with a major caveat).
As an example, consider English an & Anne. In this instance, the two typically occur in distinct prosodic environments (as a proper noun, Anne typically occurs in absolutely stressed positions, whilst as a determiner, an is used almost exclusively in positions that are absolutely unstressed), and it is this difference in prosody that allows for the distinct surface representation.
When pronounced in an environment that accepts both the two are pronounced identically (e.g. when mentioned in isolation, both are pronounced /ˈæn/).
We should then conclude that the two have the same underlying representation, despite the fact that almost all instances of them will have different surface representations.

Isn't it slighlty contrived to say that underlying representation means when pronounced in isolation?

@Lambie true. I was trying to illustrate that the environment in which the word is pronounced is important, but saying that one such environment is identical to the underlying representation probably isn't warranted. I've edited my answer to avoid making that assertion

I think this was a newbie question and maybe was more than somewhat off. Maybe I'm wrong though.  Cheers and thanks.
